# Out-of-date website content tracker

Tags: web-development

Not sure if this is really a possible option, but here goes: I have been with my current company about 7 months now, and have access to administration of the website (currently we are using Edlio for the CMS). There are multiple personnel that edit the website. I have about 200 pages for the domain.

Is there any software, preferably for free, that will alert me (through either a browser or email) when content has been outdated? I already have some content change alerts set up, but not quite what I needed. What I do need is something that will tell me when events have already passed by.

"Out of date content" is simply removing events/pages that have passed today's calendar date.

Comment: How is the content on the website being maintained? Do you have a CMS or is there someone who hand edits pages?

Comment: Currently we are using Edlio for the CMS. Not a huge fan so far as it doesn't seem to be a lot in the way of options, but it's what I have to work with. Is there perhaps something that integrates with CMS'?

Comment: Is it possible to change the CMS? They might let you if you can export, import content. To choose a new CMS there is no place better than http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

Comment: Can you please define what "when content has been outdated" means? As I commented below, it could be anything from a change in the org chart because someone started or left to removing references to the upcoming company picnic after it has occurred."   A good CMS would handle both of those for you. Time to change?

Comment: @Mawg "Out of date content" is simply removing events/pages that have passed today's calendar date. Sorry, should have been more specific on that. What CMS would anyone recommend for this stuff? And will still allow for multiple people (50ish) to still edit the page.

Comment: In that case, see CMSmatrix. I am sure that Drupal could do it, but no doubt you have other requirements, so use the CMSmatrix wizard & chose which suits you best.